# Approximating electrostatic grids as a multipole expansion

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion

Is there a known good summary, or a succinct algorithm to compute the far-field approximations of an arbitrary set of electrostatic surfaces set at different potentials?

I'm looking to model a certain set of electrostatic grids from far-away, I know the solution of the electrostatic potential near the grids by solving Laplace equation, but I can't find a simple way to translate this information and obtain the far-away field. I believe there is a simple way to compute the monopole-dipolar-quadrupolar moments of charge, but right now I can't remember the correct way to do this

Comment: If you have the local fields, why can't you determine the far fields?  Usually, the far field approximation is used because the local fields are too complicated to model while the far fields can look like a nice dipole, for instance.  Is there any reason to think you can't approximate the electric fields as a linear superposition?

Comment: If you have a copy of Jackson's E&M, he has an entire chapter (well a good fraction) devoted to multipole expansions and the ways to estimate the near- and far-field approximations from various sources.